# Bootstrap layout not coming as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have deveoped a page using bootstrap and ROR.

while running on local desktop, it was working fine and as expected and satified, i deployed it to heroku.

When i check the page, its showing weird behavior i.e. last column is moved to next row.

the website page is as follows : 
[Veggies4all.org](http://veggies4all.org/recipes/2)

I have checked rechecked all stylesheets / html and ERB files for any difference but could not find one.

Please suggest

**update**
The generated `<div class="container">` is as follows

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class = "panel panel-default">
            <div class = "panel-heading">
                Ingredients
            </div>
            <div class = "panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Butter
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class = "panel panel-default">
            <div class = "panel-heading">
                Method
            </div>
            <div class = "panel-body">
                <p>
                    <li>Please have patience</li>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class = "panel panel-default">
            <div class = "panel-heading">
                Related Categories
            </div>
            <div class = "panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Lunch
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Main Course
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Breakfast
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i check it on localhost the output is as follows 
[image: localhost snapshot]

when i try it on heroku, the output is as follows - you can also refer it at [Veggies4all.org](http://veggies4all.org/recipes/2)

[image: Heroku snapshot]

I tried running it on codelab and codeply to check the validity and is working fine there also...

is there something more i am missing?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you see and explain what would you like the layout to look like?

Comment: If you mean the "Related Categories" moving below the rest it happens because the containing div is too narrow. If you add some space all 3 elements get aligned in one line.

Comment: Please clean-up the code before posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

Malformed HTML in the `col-md-6` is causing the problem. The `li` shouldn't be the child of a `p`. There's an extra closing `</p>` after the fb-comments.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class = "panel panel-default">
        <div class = "panel-heading">
            Method
        </div>
        <div class = "panel-body">
            <p><li>Please have patience</li></p>
        </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://veggies4all.org/recipes/Coming Soon data-numposts="5" data-width="100%"></div></p>

</div>
```

Comment: am sorry the unformatted code... i have fixed the issue mentioned with extra </p>but still the issue persists.

Comment: It's not just the extra p

Comment: i have updated the code  - stripeed everything and even then i see the columns are getting wrapped - tried on codeply and other sites - it works fine but just not on heroku. is there anyother method to make it work on heroku?